# How to pod install only specific project

Tags: cocoapods

I want to install specific project using pod install with Podfile.
if I execute pod install, other project is updating.
i just want to install specific project. is any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`xcodeproj`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#xcodeproj). Otherwise the other Podfile configuration options are in the same guide.